# ASP.Net VB File Upload

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file, file-upload

I am making an ASP.Net VB web application and I am trying to upload files to the server. There is a modal popup and inside of the popup it will display an image if it exists, If it does not exist you can upload an image. The trouble is that Whenever I hit the upload button no file uploads. The page refreshes and the popup disappears. I just want it so at least the file uploads properly.

This is the asp code for the pop up

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
<div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <h2>Transaction Recipt</h2>Transaction ID:
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=''></asp:Label>
    <br /><br />

    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <br /><br />
    <br />
    <asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />

<br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick = "Button_Upload" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Row") %>' Width="75" /><br>
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</div>
```

This is the vb code for the file upload

```
Protected Sub Button_Upload(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If FileUploadControl.HasFile Then
        Try
            FileUploadControl.SaveAs("~\Images\" & _
               FileUploadControl.FileName)
            Label1.Text = "File name: " & _
               FileUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName & "<br>" & _
               "File Size: " & _
               FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength & " kb<br>" & _
               "Content type: " & _
               FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType
        Catch ex As Exception
            Label1.Text = "ERROR: " & ex.Message.ToString()
        End Try
    Else
        Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file."
    End If
End Sub
```

And this is the asp code for the whole page in case you need it

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Admin.master" AutoEventWireup="false" 

CodeFile="Ledger.aspx.vb" Inherits="Admin_Accounting_Ledger" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
    <link href="../../Styles/Admin.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Account] FROM [Accounts]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td class="style1">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" 
        Width="241px" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    DataTextField="Account" DataValueField="Account">
    </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
            </td>
            <td class="style2">
    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
        BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" ForeColor="Black" 
        GridLines="None" Height="30px" Width="241px">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" />
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Column1" HeaderText="Account Total" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="Column1" />
        </Fields>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="True" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" 
            HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:DetailsView>
                </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add Transaction" 
                    BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style1">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td class="style2">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style1">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td class="style2">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT SUM(Amount)  FROM Transactions WHERE ([Account] LIKE '%' + @Account + '%')">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Account" QueryStringField="id" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table style="width: 100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" width="150px">
                                <%# Eval("Date")%>
                            </td>
                            <td align="center" width="200px">
                                <%# Eval("Category")%>
                            </td>
                            <td align="center" >
                               <%# Eval("Amount")%>
                            </td>
                            <td align="Right" >
                                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Reciept" OnClick = "Button_Reciept" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Row") %>' Width="75" /><br>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                <br/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>


<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <h2>Transaction Recipt</h2>Transaction ID:
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=''></asp:Label>
        <br /><br />

        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br /><br />
        <br />
        <asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />

    <br /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick = "Button_Upload" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Row") %>' Width="75" /><br>
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>




    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 


        SelectCommand="SELECT [Date], [Amount], [Category], [Row] FROM [Transactions] WHERE ([Account] LIKE '%' + @Account + '%') ORDER BY Date DESC">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Account" QueryStringField="id" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1- If you are using an update panel you should use post back trigger.
2- In code behind you should use view state (Property) to store the file name and path then add it to your DB.
3- In your case i think that there is a place you are posting back the page after selecting uploaded file -trace the code-

basically you can save only the extension on the DB, and the image it self on the solution, so you can call it as you said.. you can do something like (code am using for employee images)

```
 If .EmpImagePath <> Nothing Then
                FileFullPath = .EmpImagePath
                Dim imgURL As String = Convert.ToBase64String(ConvertImageFiletoBytes(.EmpImagePath))
                Dim imgSrc As String = String.Format("data:/image/gif;base64,{0}", imgURL)
                EmpImg.ImageUrl = imgSrc
            Else
                If .Gender = "f" Then
                    EmpImg.ImageUrl = "~/images/no_photo_female.jpg"
                Else
                    EmpImg.ImageUrl = "~/images/nophoto.jpg"
                End If

            End If
```

Comment: if I write the full file path like this C:\Users\Charles\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\cbwwp\Images\ then it works. But I wanted to use something based on the root of the site like ~/Images/ any suggestions?

Comment: @user3612221 You could use [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) or [HostingEnvironment.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: you can also send the image to the pop up as query string